# How to filter cases by group based on multiple conditions in r?

Tags: r

This is the dataset I have:

```
  df = data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4), 
       Diagnosis=c("NEG","NEG","POS","NEG","NEG","NEG","NEG","POS","POS",'','',''))
```

I want to filter out the repeated cases with two conditions: 1) if the 'Diagnosis' ever equals to 'POS', then select one of the 'POS' observations; 2) if the 'Diagnosis' does not equal to 'POS', then check if 'Diagnosis' ever equals to 'NEG', then select one of the 'NEG' observations; 3) for other cases that do not sit in condition 1 and 2, just select any one of the records in the group (ID).

this is the dataset I want:

```
df = data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4), 
           Diagnosis=c("POS","NEG","POS",''))
```

this is the code I tried, but it did not get the intended results:

```
df_unique <- df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(Diagnosis==ifelse('POS' %in% Diagnosis, first(Diagnosis=='POS'),ifelse((!('POS' %in% Diagnosis)&('NEG' %in% Diagnosis)),first(Diagnosis=='POS'),first(Diagnosis))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to make `Diagnosis` an ordered factor, then `arrange` (sort) by this column and select the first row by group.

```
library(dplyr)

df$Diagnosis <- factor(df$Diagnosis, levels = c("POS", "NEG", ""), ordered = TRUE)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  arrange(Diagnosis) %>%
  slice(1)
```

**Output**

```
     ID Diagnosis
  <dbl> <ord>    
1     1 "POS"    
2     2 "NEG"    
3     3 "POS"    
4     4 ""
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `distinct`

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
df %>%
  mutate(Diagnosis = fct_relevel(Diagnosis, c("POS", "NEG", ""))) %>% 
  arrange(ID, Diagnosis) %>% 
  distinct(ID, .keep_all = TRUE)
#  ID Diagnosis
#1  1       POS
#2  2       NEG   
#3  3       POS
#4  4
```

Comment: I accepted the first answer because it provided the idea of the solution. I would definitely vote up your answer, but the new account has not enough credit to do so. Really grateful for your help.